# Terraform API add GPG key

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I've created an api token at the organization level and am trying to add a GPG key

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "gpg-keys",
    "attributes": {
      "namespace": "abc",
      "ascii-armor": "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- abc -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----"
    }  }
}
```

I am providing namespace as the exact organization name (case sensitive) of the org I got the token from.

I am getting this response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": "403",
            "title": "forbidden",
            "detail": "body namespace not authorized"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am following this docs:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/api-docs/private-registry/gpg-keys#add-a-gpg-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually just user error (or user unawareness?) - we cannot have private providers on the free tier of Terraform cloud.

A better error message would have made it easier.

Answer (score 2):

You must use a user API token to perform this operation.

You can create one on your [user settings page](https://app.terraform.io/app/settings/tokens).